# overlayfs with a lot of directories

Tags: overlayfs

Say I have an arbitrary number of directories, labeled by numbers.

I also have the directory `merge`.

I can do

```
mount -t overlay -olowerdir=1:2:50 overlay merge
```

to get the contents of `1`, `2`, and `50` in `merge`.

What is the best way to 'add' more directories to the overlay, say, `23`, `81`, and `457` as if I had done the command

```
mount -t overlay -olowerdir=1:2:50:23:81:457 overlay merge
```

in the first place?

If I want to "unoverlay" a certain directory, say `23`, can I do it without unmounting the entire thing?

Conceptually, I guess you could say I want an arbitrary number of directories on the same "level" of overlay.

Comment: You can mount it again on `merge` removing 23 from the list, with the earlier `mount` still present but inaccessible.

Comment: Try the `mount -o remount,overlaydir=foo:bar:blah` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

(I have exactly the same problem.) The only **info I could find about it, is this:**

From https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/11/10/129 :

```
Maybe it wasn't clear, but the number of lower layers isn't limited by
FILESYSTEM_MAX_STACK_DEPTH, only by the max size of the mount option buffer in
the kernel (1 page, usually 4096bytes).  So you could have a hundred read-only
layers stacked in a single overlayfs mount.

As for changing the stacking while the overlayfs is mounted: currently this is
not supported, the layers specified at the mount time remain there until the
overlay is unmounted.  Currently there's no possibility to add or remove layers
in a dynamic way, and it is definitely more tricky to implement than the static 
configuration.

-- Miklos Szeredi Mon, 10 Nov 2014
```